# Terraform Multi-providers VS explicit passing within Module

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-kubernetes

I have seen similar questions but the answers there rather addressed the formatting or workarounds which weren't that "clean". I will try to summarize my issue and hopefully can get some lean/clean solution. Thank you in advance guys!

I am creating AKS namespaces via Kubernetes provider in Terraform. Since I have 3 clusters, I want to be able to control which provider should be used to create the namespace. e.g. dev / prod

**Folder structure**

```
.terraform
    ├───modules
        └───namespace.tf
        └───module_providers.tf
    └───main-deploy
        └───main.tf
        └───main_provider.tf
```

**My Module** // **namespace.tf**

```
# Create Namespace
resource "kubernetes_namespace" "namespace-appteam" {
  metadata {
    annotations = {
      name = var.application_name
    }
    labels = {
      appname = var.application_name
    }
    name = var.application_name
  }
}
```

**My main.tf file**

```
module "appteam-test" {
  source            = "../modules/aks-module"
  application_name  = "dev-app"
  providers         = {
    kubernetes.dev  = kubernetes.dev
    kubernetes.prod  = kubernetes.prod
  }
}
```

Now since I have passed 2 providers in the **main.tf** module block! How do I control that the resource I am creating in **namespace.tf** file should use Dev or Prod provider? In short, how does the module know which resource to create with what provider if several are passed.

Note: I have `required_providers` defined in the `module_providers.tf` and providers in `main_provider.tf` folder.

**module_provider.tf**

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "3.20.0"
    }
    azuread = {
      source = "hashicorp/azuread"
      version = "2.27.0"
      
    }

    kubernetes = {
      source = "hashicorp/kubernetes"
      version = "2.12.1"
    }
  
  }
}
```

**Main_provider.tf**

```
provider "azuread" {
  alias = "AD"
}
  
provider "azurerm" {
  alias = "default"
  features {}
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  alias = "dev"
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  alias = "prod"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add alias to all your providers.

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  alias = "dev"
}
provider "kubernetes" {
      alias = "stage"
    }
```

In your main.tf file. Pass providers in module like following:

```
 providers             = {
    
    kubernetes.dev      = kubernetes.dev
    kubernetes.stage    = kubernetes.stage
    
  }
```

Now in the module_provider.tf file. You need to pass `configuration_aliases`

```
kubernetes = {
      source = "hashicorp/kubernetes"
      version = "2.12.1"
      configuration_aliases = [ kubernetes.dev, kubernetes.stage ]
    }
```

Once all the configurations are in place. You can specify the provider explicitly for resources you want. Your namespace.tf file will look like

```
resource "kubernetes_namespace" "namespace-appteam-1" {
  provider = kubernetes.dev
  metadata {
    annotations = {
      name = var.application_name
    }
    labels = {
      appname = var.application_name
    }
    name = var.application_name
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_namespace" "namespace-appteam-2" {
  provider = kubernetes.stage
  metadata {
    annotations = {
      name = var.application_name
    }
    labels = {
      appname = var.application_name
    }
    name = var.application_name
  }
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thanks a lot. These steps should be included in the official documentations Thanks a lot

Comment: @ZeeA They have it there. It's just that the language references aren't clear. Glad I could help.